# Proper android Oauth2 library / framework

Tags: android, authentication, jar, request, oauth-2.0

I've been searching day and night now for a proper OAuth2 library to use for my android app.

I came across many, including apache amber (formally leeloo) and the android developer specified one (http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html) which seems to be deceperated.

Yet none of them work or even merge with my project error free (ie. missing methods in jars).

Thus my question is, if there is ANY proper OAuth2 library out there that can be used for android. All I need is a library that allows me to retrieve an authentication code, followed by the token call which will allow autorize requests.

Any links towards an interesting project (git or w/e) are most appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The most complete library I found is [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java). I liked it so much that I wrapped it to make it more suitable to asynchronous android interaction. You can check my [PostmanLib here](https://github.com/fedepaol/PostmanLib--Rings-Twice--Android). It is supposed to make easier the asynchronous interaction AND the authentication via a webview.

Comment: I took a look at both scribe and your lib, do you have or know any documentation regarding how to use your (or scribe) lib? Basically i need to call an authentication url which will pop up a webview, allow access, retrieve an authentication code and use that code to ask the oauth server for a token to use authentorized api calls. I am totally new to this, but i begin to grasp the concepts of OAuth. All i need is something that makes everything (crystal) clear :)

Comment: Plus, scribe (and some other libraries) do not seem to manage refresh tokens?

Comment: @axd it does now

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Oltu (formerly Amber) dev mailing list, it has also been used in Android (at least the client side part).